# How to store printStackTrace into a string

Tags: java, stack-trace

How can I get the `e.printStackTrace()` and store it into a `String` variable?
I want to use the string generated by `e.printStackTrace()` later in my program.

I'm still new to Java so I'm not too familiar with `StringWriter` that I think
will be the solution. Or if you have any other ideas please let me know.  Thanks

Comment: Not actually the same question: the other question actually specifies that they just want to convert the result of `Throwable.getStackTrace()` to a string. That could contain quite a bit less information than would be shown by `Throwable.printStackTrace`.

Answer (score 497, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
return errors.toString();
```

Ought to be what you need.

Relevant documentation:

- [StringWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html)
- [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)
- [Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)

Comment: @Zach L - Thanks for your answer. it worked for me to print the stack trace along with personalized(Customized) error message. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This prints the nested causes of the thrown exception too which is just what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: what about closing `PrintWriter` after usage to release resources? Reading the docs I found that is not necessary for StringWriter.

Answer (score 78):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) makes this easy with [Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(Throwable)](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html#getStackTraceAsString-java.lang.Throwable-):

```
Exception e = ...
String stackTrace = Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(e);
```

Internally, this does what @Zach L suggests.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(Throwable t);` from Apache Commons 3 class `org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils`.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

[ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(Throwable t)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getStackTrace(java.lang.Throwable))

Code example:

```
try {

  // your code here

} catch(Exception e) {
  String s = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You have to use `getStackTrace ()` method instead of `printStackTrace()`. Here is a [good example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=78):

```
import java.io.*;

/**
* Simple utilities to return the stack trace of an
* exception as a String.
*/
public final class StackTraceUtil {

  public static String getStackTrace(Throwable aThrowable) {
    final Writer result = new StringWriter();
    final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
    aThrowable.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    return result.toString();
  }

  /**
  * Defines a custom format for the stack trace as String.
  */
  public static String getCustomStackTrace(Throwable aThrowable) {
    //add the class name and any message passed to constructor
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder( "BOO-BOO: " );
    result.append(aThrowable.toString());
    final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    result.append(NEW_LINE);

    //add each element of the stack trace
    for (StackTraceElement element : aThrowable.getStackTrace() ){
      result.append( element );
      result.append( NEW_LINE );
    }
    return result.toString();
  }

  /** Demonstrate output.  */
  public static void main (String... aArguments){
    final Throwable throwable = new IllegalArgumentException("Blah");
    System.out.println( getStackTrace(throwable) );
    System.out.println( getCustomStackTrace(throwable) );
  }
}
```

Comment: [Zach's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812589/822870) is 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 14):

Along the lines of Guava, Apache Commons Lang has `ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace` in `org.apache.commons.lang.exception`. [From a prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/stacktrace-to-string-in-java) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7):

```
StackTraceElement[] stack = new Exception().getStackTrace();
String theTrace = "";
for(StackTraceElement line : stack)
{
   theTrace += line.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the apache commons-lang3 lib

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;

//...

String[] ss = ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseStackTrace(e);
logger.error(StringUtils.join(ss, System.lineSeparator()));
```

Comment: `logger.error(StringUtils.join(ss, System.lineSeparator()));`

Answer (score 1):

```
call:  getStackTraceAsString(sqlEx)

public String getStackTraceAsString(Exception exc)  
{  
String stackTrace = "*** Error in getStackTraceAsString()";

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( baos );
exc.printStackTrace(ps);
try {
    stackTrace = baos.toString( "UTF8" ); // charsetName e.g. ISO-8859-1
    } 
catch( UnsupportedEncodingException ex )
    {
    Logger.getLogger(sss.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
ps.close();
try {
    baos.close();
    } 
catch( IOException ex )
    {
    Logger.getLogger(sss.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
return stackTrace;
}
```

Comment: Using a PrintWriter with a StringWriter seems to be more straightforward.

Comment: Closing the `PrintWriter` closes the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.