# e.printStackTrace in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, error-handling

I have the following `try` and `catch` snippet.

```
try{
    ...

} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.print("error");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`error` is displayed in admin console but I can't see the `e.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 4):

`printStackTrace` outputs to standard error, and `System.out` outputs to standard output. You can redirect the stack trace to standard output:

```
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(System.out));
```

Then it will appear in the admin console.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to convert the stack trace to a string and then you can log it or print it the same as the string you're already printing.

Here's how to get the stack track as a string: [How to store printStackTrace into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812570/how-to-store-printstacktrace-into-a-string)