# NullPointerException inside catch part

Tags: java

I have a code like:

```
try{
    //todo somethins
} catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
}
```

And I catched `NullPointerException`  on row `Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());` at google analytic page
How is it possible?

Comment: Please post the stack trace and better describe the issue. Is `e` a `NullPointereException` or does invoking `Log.e` cause a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: `Log` is probably `null` if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: How do you know that you catched a NullPointerException? You are catching _any_ Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your e.getMessage() is probably null. The exception that you are catching doesn't have a message.

Also don't try to catch raw exceptions. You could use NullPointerException.

See this link: [Exception.getMessage() is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237080/exception-getmessage-is-null)