# Difference between printStackTrace() and toString()

Tags: java

I'm curious as to what the difference is between printStackTrace() and toString().
At first sight, they **seem** to do the exact same thing.

Code:

```
try {
// Some code
} catch (Exception e)
   e.printStackTrace();
   // OR
   e.toString()
}
```

Comment: Ummm, they are vaguely related, but they don't do the same thing at all.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to print the result of `toString()` to `System.err`...?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

No, there is an important difference! Using toString, you only have the type of the exception and the error message. Using printStackTrace() you get the whole stacktrace of an exception, which is very helpful for debugging.

Example of System.out.println(toString()):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: yourFile.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Example of printStackTrace():

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: yourFile.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:106)
at java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:55)
at ReadFromFile.main(ReadFromFile.java:14)
```

To make a string of the whole stacktrace, I usually use this method:

```
public static String exceptionStacktraceToString(Exception e)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
    e.printStackTrace(ps);
    ps.close();
    return baos.toString();
}
```

Also note that simply calling `toString()` simply returns a string, and won't print anything out.

Comment: is there any way to store the stacktrace as a string?

Comment: +1 for the specific example of what `toString()` returns.  The method is also helpful, though I prefer @RenaudBlue's one-line version.

Answer (score 63):

To convert StackTrace to String a shorter implementation I use is:

```
public static String exceptionStacktraceToString(Exception e)
{
    return Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace());
}
```

Comment: And much more useful, too, than direct printing. But as one string, attention to that!

Comment: If your project uses Apache commons-lang, this can also be accomplished with `org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(Throwable)`, which will format it nicely as well

Comment: Note that this output would be different from `printStackTrace()` since `printStackTrace()` includes its cause's stacktrace recursively, whereas `getStackTrace()` does not.

Answer (score 14):

No, there's a huge difference. If you *just* call `toString`, it *won't print anything* - it will just *return* a string. A catch block of just `e.toString();` is useless. (There's also the matter of the stack trace, as Martijn pointed out.)

Personally I wouldn't use either though - I'd use a logging library (log4j, java.util.logging etc) which takes the `Throwable` itself as a parameter, and will format it usefully - including the stack trace, potentially truncated to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 1):

`toString ()` gives name of the exception class when exception is raised and `printStackTrace ()` gives the entry hierarchy of method execution that were there when exception is raised in the application.

For the code

```
    try 
    {
        List<String>  n =new ArrayList<String>();
        String i = n.get(3); 
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

`e.printStackTrace()` will give

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at com.o2.business.util.Trial.test(CommonUtilsTest.java:866)
```

While `e.toString()` will not print anything as Jon wrote in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to get the output of `Throwable.printStackTrace()`, just like what I was looking for. I checked the Java source code and put together a `String` instead of writing to a `PrintStream`. It is somewhat more comprehensive than @MartijnCourteaux solution but feels a little like a hack to me.

As for your answer, you can actually see that `Throwable.toString()` is only a part of `Throwable.printStackTrace()`:

```
public static String getStackTraceString(Throwable e) {
    return getStackTraceString(e, "");
}

private static String getStackTraceString(Throwable e, String indent) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(e.toString());
    sb.append("\n");

    StackTraceElement[] stack = e.getStackTrace();
    if (stack != null) {
        for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : stack) {
            sb.append(indent);
            sb.append("\tat ");
            sb.append(stackTraceElement.toString());
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    }

    Throwable[] suppressedExceptions = e.getSuppressed();
    // Print suppressed exceptions indented one level deeper.
    if (suppressedExceptions != null) {
        for (Throwable throwable : suppressedExceptions) {
            sb.append(indent);
            sb.append("\tSuppressed: ");
            sb.append(getStackTraceString(throwable, indent + "\t"));
        }
    }

    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    if (cause != null) {
        sb.append(indent);
        sb.append("Caused by: ");
        sb.append(getStackTraceString(cause, indent));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: FYI: just found out that on Android you can use [Log.getStackTraceString(java.lang.Throwable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#getStackTraceString(java.lang.Throwable) "Android getStackTraceString(java.lang.Throwable)") directly.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I use for the full stack trace as a `String`

```
public static @NotNull String toString(@NotNull Throwable e) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
    return sw.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an Open Source java library called MgntUtils (written by me) that provides several methods that allow you to extract stacktrace  as a String as well as to optionally filter based on parametric package prefix. See the javadoc for the method [public static java.lang.String getStacktrace(java.lang.Throwable e,
                             boolean cutTBS,
                             java.lang.String relevantPackage)](https://appdoc.app/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/com/mgnt/utils/TextUtils.html#getStacktrace(java.lang.Throwable,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String))
The library is available at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils&core=gav) and [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)