# How do I write the exception from printStackTrace() into a text file in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I need to capture the exception in a text file in Java.  For example:

```
try {
  File f = new File("");
}
catch(FileNotFoundException f) {
  f.printStackTrace();  // instead of printing into console it should write into a text file    
  writePrintStackTrace(f.getMessage()); // this is my own method where I store f.getMessage() into a text file.
}
```

Using `getMessage()` works, but it only shows the error message.  I want all the information in the `printStackTrace()` including line numbers.

Comment: Why don't you use a logging framework? That's what they are good at.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It accepts a `PrintStream` as a parameter; see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29).

```
File file = new File("test.log");
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file);
try {
    // something
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(ps);
}
ps.close();
```

See also [Difference between printStackTrace() and toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120709/difference-between-printstacktrace-and-tostring)

Comment: @Qnan Google is not always up to date. ;)

Comment: and what if we want to append into each of it ?

Answer (score 10):

Try to expand on this simple example:

```
catch (Exception e) {

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("file.txt"));
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
    pw.close();
}
```

As you can see, `printStackTrace()` has overloads.

Answer (score 4):

Do set the err/out stream using `System` class.

```
PrintStream newErr;
PrintStream newOut;
// assign FileOutputStream to these two objects. And then it will be written on your files.
System.setErr(newErr);
System.setOut(newOut);
```

Comment: or else go for a logging framework like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2)

Answer (score 2):

There is an API in `Throwable` interface `getStackTrace()` which is used internally for printing in console by `printStackTrace()`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()

Try this API to get `StackTraceElement` and print those elements sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below example helps you-

```
package com.kodehelp.javaio;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class PrintStackTraceToFile {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      PrintStream ps= null;
      try {
          ps = new PrintStream(new File("/sample.log"));
          throw new FileNotFoundException("Sample Exception");
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(ps);
      }
    }
}
```

For more detail, refer to this link [here](https://kodehelp.com/write-exceptions-printstacktrace-file-in-java/)