# Output exception in the file

Tags: java, file, exception, jdbc, sqlexception

There is a unit of a code

```
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How
to output result of execution of the operator in the file

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

?

Comment: You really don't want to output `e.printStackTrace()` to a file, and can't unless you redirecting the standard error stream to your file. Better I think to log the stacktrace using logging using either the logging that comes with Java or a 3rd party log utility.

Comment: ^^ See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477607/avoid-printstacktrace-use-a-logger-call-instead

Comment: @BrianRoach's suggestion and link is what I meant to say!

Comment: That said, this Q is a dup: possible duplicate of [How to write exception(printStackTrace()) into txt file in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053075/how-to-write-exceptionprintstacktrace-into-txt-file-in-java)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You can use `e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(new File(filename)))`