# Is it possible in Java's MessageFormat to receive a stack trace?

Tags: java, stack-trace, messageformat

Code:

```
String message = MessageFormat.format("error {0}",e);
```

E.g. message:

```
     java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "sdf sf sa dg "
```

I need to receive all the stack trace, like:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "sdf sf sa dg "
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 ................
```

Is this possible ?
Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/stacktrace-to-string-in-java) which talks about how to convert an exception to String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method to capture the stacktrace in a String

```
public String getStackTrace(Throwable t) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    t.printStackTrace(pw);
    pw.flush();
    return sw.toString();
}
```

EDIT: the [SO article linked by Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/stacktrace-to-string-in-java?lq=1) is also a very good read!