# how to print an exception using logger?

Tags: java, exception, logging

I have a situation in which I want to print all the exception caught in catch block using logger.

```
 try {
        File file = new File("C:\\className").mkdir();
        fh = new FileHandler("C:\\className\\className.log");
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e);
    }
```

i got the error logger cannot be applied to `java.io.Exception...`

My concern is if I do so many thing in try block and I keep only one catch block as catch(Exception e), Then is there any way using logger that print any kind of exception caught in catch block ? 
Note: we are using java.util.logging.Logger API

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1149718/112500

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/stacktrace-to-string-in-java

Comment: Generally logfile name, format etc are left outside the code so that it can be tweaked in production.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should probably clarify which logger are you using.

`org.apache.commons.logging.Log` interface has method `void error(Object message, Throwable t)` (and method `void info(Object message, Throwable t)`), which logs the stack trace together with your custom message. Log4J implementation has this method too.

So, probably you need to write:

```
logger.error("BOOM!", e);
```

If you need to log it with INFO level (though, it might be a strange use case), then:

```
logger.info("Just a stack trace, nothing to worry about", e);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Kadelakig sorry, we are using java.util.looging API

Comment: Oh I see. It seems that there also is somewhat similar functionality: `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("Test").log(Level.INFO, "BOOM!", e);` <-- this worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Use: `LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Got an exception.", e);`
 
or  `LOGGER.info("Got an exception. " + e.getMessage())`;

Comment: If exception is unexpected then I recommend to use SEVERE of WARNING log level for log message

Comment: Yes, for unexpected exceptions that would probably be true. I was answering the question though, where the questioner was using info log level to log and hence my example using info.

Answer (score 4):

Try to log the stack trace like below:

```
logger.error("Exception :: " , e);
```

Comment: i tried this, got the error Symbol not found    symbol  : method error(java.lang.String,java.io.IOException)
 location: class java.util.logging.Logger
                     logger.error("Exception:: ",e);

Comment: @Pankaj Aren't you using Log4j for logging. The method is present in `org.apache.log4j.Logger`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to log the exception stack to String

```
 public String stackTraceToString(Throwable e) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (StackTraceElement element : e.getStackTrace()) {
        sb.append(element.toString());
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```