# How to save ERROR logs in to a database with JDBC Appender

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, log4j, appender

I would like to save the stacktrace of exceptions to a mysql database using JDBC appender. The issue here is I don't want to use e.printstacktrace in my code. Is there a way to go about?

Comment: Yes, use a logging library. And given you tagged log4j, you already know about their existence, so what is your real question?

Comment: I'm using DB appender and saving logs into a table. But I would like to save Exceptions with it's stacktrace into my database. When I use the following code it does not save the stack trace into my table. What's the recommended way of saving a stack trace as an error log into a table?

catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(" ::: An exception occurred :::: " + e);
}

Comment: Have you even looked at the log4j API? There are log methods that explicitly take a `Throwable` (the super-class of exceptions), or if they take multiple object parameters, then you put the exception last.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805460/how-to-print-an-exception-using-logger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to convert the stacktrace to a string by using [ExceptionUtil](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) class. Once the stacktrace is converted to a string I was able to save the error log using the DB appender as described below.

```
try{
    //Some code that throws an exception
    }

catch(SomeException e)
    {
    String stackTrace = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e);
    log.error(":: An error has occurred :::: " + stackTrace);
    }
```