# How do I redirect output of Getopt error message to a string?

Tags: java

I need to store `Getopt` class error message to a string.

Normally that error will be printed in standard error console.

How would I do this?

Comment: I dont understand your question.

Comment: Do you mean an **exception**? [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/stacktrace-to-string-in-java). However, we wouldn't have to guess if you showed us your code, and your exact requirements, and what the code does instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use [`System.setOut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) and/or [`System.setErr`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29).

As an example:

```
static void printMessage()
{
  System.out.println("Hello");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
  // ByteArrayOutputStream = in-memory output stream
  OutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  PrintStream oldStream = System.out; // store the current output stream
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(output)); // change the output stream
  printMessage(); // call function that prints to System.out
  System.setOut(oldStream); // restore the old output stream
  System.out.println("Output from stream: " + output.toString());
}
```

The above will lead to only the following output:

```
Output from stream: Hello
```