# Debugging in GWT Super Dev Mode?

Tags: java, debugging, gwt, source-maps, gwt-super-dev-mode

So far, debugging in GWT super dev mode seems to be a real pain. If there are any errors, there is no stack trace, just a cryptic message given in the chrome console. Is there a way to get all errors to print a stack trace, like in the dev mode?

I already have source maps on I believe, since if I go to Sources in Chrome's dev tools, I can see the source code of my java classes.

Comment: Hi, have you found a way to see java exception stack trace in superdev mode ?

Comment: @ice13ill No, the best i've found is to turn on source maps, and try to debug from chrome's console. If you set a watch / breakpoint in chrome's console, it will break at it and you could step through it.

Comment: Right, so that means that (if you have a big/complex code) you would have to somehow guess what variable could be problematic, and add a watch to it?

Comment: @ice13ill Actually, look at `GWT.setUnhandledExceptionHandler`. That will let you set the exception handler, and then you can print the stack trace of that exception to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler` lets you set an exception handler, which will handle all exceptions. You can then get the stacktrace of that exception using something like [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1149712/49153), and then print `exception.toString()` and the stack trace to the console. This has worked reasonably well for me.

Answer (score 0):

How do you start super dev mode? From inside eclipse maybe?
If you have a maven project and run it from the command line (e.g. mvn gwt:run) a window pops up showing you the stack traces of exceptions and other information as well.

Comment: I'm using Maven, with IntelliJ. That window only seems to show compile  errors, not runtime errors..