# Debugging in GWT 2.7 Super Dev Mode, stackTrace is missing?

Tags: java, gwt

I just migrated from GWT 2.5.1 to 2.7 and first time using SuperDev Mode.
I have enabled "JavaScript source maps" in Chrome dev tools.
In Chrome Console exception looks like this:

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: For input string: "a"
  at fillInStackTrace_0_g$
  at Throwable_3_g$
  at Exception_3_g$
  at RuntimeException_3_g$
  at UmbrellaException_3_g$
  at UmbrellaException_5_g$
  at fireEvent_1_g$
  at fireEvent_3_g$
  at fireNativeEvent_1_g$
  at onBrowserEvent_2_g$
  at dispatchEventImpl_0_g$
  at dispatchEvent_4_g$
  at dispatchEvent_6_g$
  at apply_0_g$
  at entry0_0_g$
  at <anonymous>
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
  at fillInStackTrace_0_g$
  at Throwable_2_g$
  at Exception_2_g$
  at RuntimeException_2_g$
  at IllegalArgumentException_2_g$
  at NumberFormatException_2_g$
  at forInputString_0_g$
  at __parseAndValidateDouble_0_g$
  at parseDouble_0_g$
  at Double_2_g$
  at valueOf_68_g$
  at onClick_109_g$
  at dispatch_6_g$
  at dispatch_7_g$
  at dispatch_1_g$
  at dispatchEvent_2_g$
  at doFire_0_g$
  at fireEvent_2_g$
  at fireEvent_1_g$
  at fireEvent_3_g$
  at fireNativeEvent_1_g$
  at onBrowserEvent_2_g$
  at dispatchEventImpl_0_g$
  at dispatchEvent_4_g$
  at dispatchEvent_6_g$
  at apply_0_g$
  at entry0_0_g$
  at <anonymous>
```

OnModuleLoad I am cacthing exceptions:

```
GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
            GWT.log(e);
        }
    });
```

How can I get stackTrace?
I tried something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24334132/1660637 but couldn't manage to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding these into your gwt.xml file?

```
<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated"/>
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" value="true"/>
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames" value="true"/>
```

Comment: No I didn't. I just tried but I get same console log.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/8998) for SuperDevMode, stacktraces and the use of `GWT.log`.
Also there seem to be [improvements](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/8998) in GWT 2.8.

As far as I know if you use the normal `java.util.logging` instead of `GWT.log` you should get stack traces in SDM.

Answer (score 0):

Call the below method from your onModuleLoad.
Note that you must use java.util.Logging for this to work. GWT.log does not work correctly for exceptions.

/**
    * Set an uncaught exception handler that unwraps the exception
    * (UmbrellaException) for SuperDevMode.
    */
   private void setUncaughtExceptionHandler()
   {
      GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
      {
         @Override
         public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e)
         {
            Throwable unwrapped = unwrap(e);
            BootBox.error(I18NMessages.getMessage(3774) + "\n\n" + unwrapped);
            LOGGER.log(Level.EXCEPTION, "onUncaughtException " + e.getMessage(), unwrapped);
         }

```
     public Throwable unwrap(Throwable e)
     {
        if (e instanceof UmbrellaException)
        {
           UmbrellaException ue = (UmbrellaException) e;
           if (ue.getCauses().size() == 1)
           {
              return unwrap(ue.getCauses().iterator().next());
           }
        }
        return e;
     }
  });
```

}

And the LOGGER is create in the following way

```
public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("Something");
```

Comment: And what is BootBox and I18NMessages?

Comment: BootBox is something from GWT bootstrap 3.
That line just displays a popup with an error message.