# How to get logcat in UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: android, exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I'm writing a custom exception handler that basically reports every crash of an application and i want to get logcat output after an exception occurs. That's the easy part, i just use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
```

But that only gives me all of the logcat that occured prior to the exception, e.g. i dont get the FATAL part of the exception. So if my app crashes two times i will get the first FATAL signal in the second crash.

Is there a way around this? Using a Thread.sleep is not really an option, unless the sleep is really small, but that seems kind-of hackish...

Comment: or printStackTrace() dosent work?

Comment: Personally I just put try/catch blocks around any bit of code which might throw an exception including multiple catch blocks where necessary as well as a final generic catch for `Exception`. In all of them I either compensate or retry operations or I simply use `e.prinStackTrace` to indicate what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way around this?

[Capture the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380001/115145) of the `Exception` that you caught.

Comment: I'm already doing this, but i would also like it to appear in the logcat output (so there wouldn't be any confusion when dealing with multiple crashes).

Comment: @Squeazer: Well, by definition, it will not appear in the LogCat output until after you allow it to appear in the LogCat output, by re-throwing the exception or otherwise allowing the default exception handling logic to appear.

Comment: But if i, for instance, use my custom `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, and get the logcat as i described above, then after the crash i capture the logcat through adb it will appear there. Is there any way i can get that inside my handler or does the app have to exit / the handler has to finish before it writes the exception to logcat?

Comment: @Squeazer: "Is there any way i can get that inside my handler" -- no. "does the app have to exit / the handler has to finish before it writes the exception to logcat?" -- yes.

Comment: well that sucks. Thanks for the help!