# Vaadin: find whether currently in a UI thread or not

Tags: java, vaadin

In my Vaadin app, I have some class methods that can both be called from an event triggered in the server or due to a user action.

I need a way to find out whether current code is executing in a UI thread (a thread that is currently handling a request from the UI) or not.

Is there a way for this. Can I assume that if `UI.getCurrent()` returns non null reference, this is a UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

[From documentation](http://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.rc2/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#getCurrent%28%29):

> Gets the currently used UI. The current UI is automatically defined when processing requests to the server. In other cases, (e.g. from **background threads**), the **current UI is not** automatically defined.

The other way of checking it would be by obtaining current stacktrace and looking into it (for com.vaadin calls). Tons of examples are here: [How can I convert a stack trace to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/how-can-i-convert-a-stack-trace-to-a-string)

Comment: I played around with threads a little and found that it is not the case. If I start a new thread from a UI thread, new thread also returns a valid `VaadinSession` if I called `VaadinSession.getCurrent()`. Thread locals get inherited to newly created thread.

Comment: Still, the method with obtaining stacktrace will work.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by `obtaining stacktrace` but I don't think it is appropriate to access UI elements just because `VaadinSession.getCurrent()` returned a non null reference. Because current thread  can be just another thread which got `VaadinSession` thread local from its parent UI thread. If I do so, since `VaadinSession` is not locked by current thread, it may cause problems.

Comment: For that, use [`ui.accesss`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#access%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3667892) by Johannes Dahlströms, no - you cannot rely on a null value:

> Well, yes and no.
>
> The reference returned by UI.getCurrent() is stored in an *inheritable
>   ThreadLocal*. When a UI is accessed, either via a client request, or by
>   the user invoking UI.access(), the UI.getCurrent() value is set to
>   that UI.
>
> In an arbitrary background thread, outside a UI.access() invocation,
>   there cannot be a concept of a "current UI". Why, then,
>   UI.getCurrent() in many cases does return a non-null value even in a
>   background thread? This is because, as mentioned, the ThreadLocal is
>   inheritable. That is to say, if a child thread is spawned by a thread
>   that at that time has UI.getCurrent() set, the value is inherited by
>   the child thread. This is most likely the effect you're seeing. It
>   makes some things a bit more convenient, but I'm not actually sure
>   it's actually a good idea for it to be inheritable - it stretches the
>   meaning of "current" and may cause the user to forget to do proper
>   synchronization before accessing the "current" UI.