# How to get entire backtrace from Throwable ex

Tags: java, android

I've implemented the following code to get crash details:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
  @Override
  public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Uncaught Exception!");
    StackTraceElement stackTraceElements[] = ex.getStackTrace();
  }
});
```

The problem I'm facing is, let's say two exceptions occur, `RuntimeException` which was caused by `NullPointerException`. In the above method, I'm getting trace for only `RuntimeException`.
What should I do to get entire the back trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getCause()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause--) method

```
ex.getCause().getStackTrace()
```

Comment: Note that getCause() can return null.

Comment: I looked into doc before posting, how silly of me, didn't notice this method!

Comment: yes, I can have loop till it returns null, thanks @bedrin!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
t.printStackTrace(pw);
sw.toString(); // stack trace as a string
```

This will give you the complete stack trace. For other ways of getting the same please go through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/how-can-i-convert-a-stack-trace-to-a-string). Above has been copied from the same thread

Comment: This does work, but I wasn't looking for exact string, I wanted to format it my way and hence hence was looking for all `Throwable`s back traced.
Thanks anyways!