# Print Stacktrace into Textarea in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, exception, javafx-8, stack-trace, printstacktrace

I would like to print the stacktrace of a throwable into a Textarea

Something like this:

```
textArea.setText(throwableElement.toString() + "\n" + throwableElement.printStackTrace());
```

Is that possible?

I hope you can help me

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a stack trace to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/how-can-i-convert-a-stack-trace-to-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
StringWriter stackTraceWriter = new StringWriter();
throwableElement.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTraceWriter));
textArea.setText(throwableElement.toString() + "\n" + stackTraceWriter.toString());
```