# How to make log4j syslog appender write a stack trace in one line?

Tags: java, log4j, syslog

I am using log4j syslog appender and notice that when an exception occurs the appender writes every entry in the stack trace as a new line.

Is there a way to configure it so that the entire stack trace will go as one line instead of multiple lines?

Comment: I am not sure you can do that, as I don't believe it's log4j that is actually doing the stacktrace write.  You could write it out to a string and remove the carriage returns.

Comment: What about Pattern Layouts?

Comment: It looks like @davidhxx answered your question, but my point was that I was under the impression that Log4J, and all logging utils, simply used `Throwable.printStackTrace()` to output the stack trace, and in which case you probably wouldn't be able to easily change the formatting.  However, it looks like Log4J, per the answer below, has some sort of provision to handle it, which I am guessing uses one of the overridden `printStackTrace()` calls to write the values out to a stream/writer so that you can alter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the renderer of the stacktraces.
There are two available `ThrowableRenderer` in Log4J ( `org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableRenderer` Interface)
One is used by default.
So, implements your own ThrowableRenderer with your wished formatting and then set it in your configuration.

In Log4j 1, it works. Never try in Log42.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html

> ThrowableRenderer
>       You can customize the way an instance of Throwable is converted to String
>       before being logged. This is done by specifying an ThrowableRenderer.
>       The syntax is:
>      log4j.throwableRenderer=fully.qualified.name.of.rendering.class
>      log4j.throwableRenderer.paramName=paramValue
>   As in,
>      log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedThrowableRenderer

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention I'm using this inside JBOSS Fuse so very limited to what I can do code wise, only able to change Log4J properties. Are there any renderers I can use already?

Comment: I don't see why you could not create your own render class and put in the classpath place of JBoss (for example the lib dir). JBoss has this dir : common/lib. JBoss fuse has not that ? There are two renderers but they does not make what you want. DefaultThrowableRenderer and EnhancedThrowableRenderer.

Comment: While this works, it will still send the log message and the stacktrace as two separate syslog messages.

Comment: @bmaupin Are you sure ? That is pity. Whatever the proposed solutions by you and James are clearly better because it avoids create a class besides the log4j configuration file.

Comment: @davidxxx Whatever bmaupin suggested sounds good but doesn't work. At least for me it does not work. See please the comments I added to his answer. Do you have any idea? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623141/custom-throwablerenderer-not-working-log4j-1-x Can you help with some ideas?

Answer (score 11):

I'm using the following log4j2 configuration which is working well sending to syslog and doesn't require code changes to convert all those exceptions to strings.  It's just replacing the default linesep with a pipe on exceptions.

```
    <Syslog name="SYSLOG" host="127.0.0.1" port="515" protocol="TCP" charset="UTF-8"
            immediateFail="false" ignoreExceptions="true" reconnectionDelayMillis="250">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d] %-5p %m%n %throwable{separator(|)}"></PatternLayout>
    </Syslog>
```

Comment: Great solution. maybe you should consider replacing the pipeline for \u2028 that happens to be designed for that.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is how you would use `\u2028` in the PatternLayout (since it expects XML escape codes; `\u` codes won't work): `%throwable{separator(&#8232;)}`

Comment: @bmaupin  &#8232; how did you get this ?

Comment: @Krish there are a number of ways to get it. Normally what I do is I put something like "unicode 2028" in a search engine and most of the sites that list unicode characters will show the equivalent HTML/XML, e.g. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm

Answer (score 5):

#### Log4j2

See [james' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55407412/399105).

#### Log4j v1

By default, the syslog appender will send the formatted log as well as each line of the stack trace as separate log entries in syslog. Because syslog uses UDP, the lines may be out of order.

If that's the problem you're trying to solve, then as [james mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55407412/399105) the best way to do this is to use a pattern layout with the `%throwable` conversion character. He documented how to do it for log4j2. For log4j1, it requires the [EnhancedPatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html):

```xml
<appender name="syslog" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
  <param name="SyslogHost" value="127.0.0.1:514"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d] %-5p %m%n%throwable"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

**Note** that the above solution will still use newline characters to separate the individual lines of the stack trace, but it will solve the problem of the stack trace lines being sent as separate log entries in syslog.

If you really want the stack trace on one line, a quick fix is to use the above example with `%throwable{short}` or `%throwable{1}`, which will only include the first line of the stack trace.

If you want the entire stack trace in one line, you may prefer to use a custom `ThrowableRenderer` as
[proposed by davidxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38486720/399105). (**Note** that this will still send the formatted log to syslog separately from the stack trace, so to avoid that you can combine this solution with the one above.)

For example:

```java
import org.apache.log4j.DefaultThrowableRenderer;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableRenderer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CustomThrowableRenderer implements ThrowableRenderer {
    private final DefaultThrowableRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultThrowableRenderer();

    @Override
    public String[] doRender(Throwable throwable) {
        String[] defaultRepresentation = defaultRenderer.doRender(throwable);
        String[] newRepresentation = {String.join("|", Arrays.asList(defaultRepresentation))};

        return newRepresentation;
    }
}
```

And then in your log4j.xml:

```xml
<throwableRenderer class="CustomThrowableRenderer"/>
```

Comment: Using EnhancedPatternLayout and %throwable doesn't seem to do anything useful in log4j 1.x. It still prints the stack trace in multiple lines. Why do you say this works?

Comment: Is this solution (which you suggest) specific to the appender? Should not be, right? I am using ConsoleAppender.

Comment: In the https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html I don't see anything which suggests to support showing the stack trace in a single line.

Comment: @peter.petrov Great feedback, thanks! I've updated my answer to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score -4):

Instead of just passing the exception to the logger (e.g. `log.error(e)`), first convert the stack trace to a string and log the string.

The most upvoted answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/how-can-i-convert-a-stack-trace-to-a-string) have a couple of easy ways to convert the stack trace to a string.

Comment: It's not a conventional way to log. You can forget to do log.error(e) and call the classic and common shared way. 
Keep common shared good practices is important in software development.