# Custom ThrowableRenderer not working log4j 1.x

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, wildfly

I am trying to get a custom throwableRenderer to work with log4j 1.2.17.
Note that I cannot upgrade to log4j2 at this stage so I am looking for 1.x solution.

See e.g.
[How to make log4j syslog appender write a stack trace in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486248/how-to-make-log4j-syslog-appender-write-a-stack-trace-in-one-line)

I am trying to do just that - get the stack trace to be printed on 1 line. I tried 2 approaches I could find on the web - using custom renderer and using Enhanced Pattern Layout. Still no luck!

But the class `WRThrowableRenderer` (which is my custom renderer)
and its method `doRender` is simply not called.
This is all in a web app running inside WildFly 8 (Java 8).

I tried at least 10 different things while testing the two approaches but nothing works.

**What am I doing wrong?!**

Also, is this renderer supposed to affect all loggers and change their behavior when an exception is logged? I think so. I am asking this because I have child loggers under this rootLogger. And they all log via the rootLogger in one single file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.throwableRenderer=com.yb.common.logging.WRThrowableRenderer

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
# log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] ###%c{20}:%L### - [[[%m]]]%n
# log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] ###%c{20}### [[[%m]]]%n %throwable{separator(|)}
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] ###%c{20}### [[[%m]]]%n
# log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.appender.stdout.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.immediateFlush=true
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to do just that - get the stack trace to be printed on 1 line. I tried 2 approaches I could find on the web - using custom renderer and using Enhanced Pattern Layout.

#### Without a custom ThrowableRenderer

If you want the stack trace all on one line without using a custom `ThrowableRenderer`, the best you'll be able to do is get the first line of the stack trace.

For example, using this configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %-5p %m %throwable{short}%n
```

Will generate this log:

```
[2020-11-20 10:54:53,454] ERROR Test error message, with stack trace java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test exception message
```

#### With a custom ThrowableRenderer

If you want the entire stack trace printed on one line, you'll need to use a custom ThrowableRenderer.

1. Create the custom ThrowableRenderer, e.g.

   ```java
   package org.example;

   import org.apache.log4j.DefaultThrowableRenderer;
   import org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableRenderer;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Arrays;

   public class CustomThrowableRenderer implements ThrowableRenderer {
       private final DefaultThrowableRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultThrowableRenderer();

       @Override
       public String[] doRender(Throwable throwable) {
           String[] defaultRepresentation = defaultRenderer.doRender(throwable);
           String[] newRepresentation = {String.join("|", Arrays.asList(defaultRepresentation))};

           return newRepresentation;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Configure log4j1 to use the custom ThrowableRenderer

   ```
   log4j.throwableRenderer=org.example.CustomThrowableRenderer
   ```

At this point, the stack trace portion of the log will all be on one line, although it may be on a separate line from the rest of the log.

For example, your configuration from above:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] ###%c{20}### [[[%m]]]%n
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.example.CustomThrowableRenderer
```

Will generate two lines because the stack trace is put on its own line by default:

```
2020-11-20 11:45:04.706 ERROR [main] ###org.example.App### [[[Test error message, with stack trace]]]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test exception message|     at org.example.App.logErrorWithStackTrace(App.java:31)| at org.example.App.okayThatsEnough(App.java:25)|        at org.example.App.notLongEnough(App.java:21)|  at org.example.App.makeStackTraceLonger(App.java:17)|   at org.example.App.testLoggingWithStackTraces(App.java:13)|     at org.example.App.main(App.java:9)
```

You can get the error message and stack trace on one line by using `%throwable` in your pattern:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] ###%c{20}### [[[%m]]] %throwable%n
```

However a blank line will be generated after:

```
2020-11-20 11:46:46.897 ERROR [main] ###org.example.App### [[[Test error message, with stack trace]]] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test exception message|       at org.example.App.logErrorWithStackTrace(App.java:31)| at org.example.App.okayThatsEnough(App.java:25)|        at org.example.App.notLongEnough(App.java:21)|  at org.example.App.makeStackTraceLonger(App.java:17)|   at org.example.App.testLoggingWithStackTraces(App.java:13)|     at org.example.App.main(App.java:9)
```

That could probably be fixed as well but it might require a custom appender.

I made a small sample app you can use as a reference: https://github.com/bmaupin/junkpile/tree/master/java/log4j1-custom-throwablerenderer

Comment: Thanks... I did a hack/patch in log4j and I have my things working now. But maybe the solution you suggest here is better. I will have to look into it.