# UncaughtExceptionHandler issue

Tags: android, stack-trace, uncaughtexceptionhandler

In the following code I am obtaining exception data in an released app.  This app is not running in debug mode - it is running as a released app on lots of phones.

What I have here works just fine.  It puts exception data into shared memory which I mail to myself the next time the app runs.  My problem is that the data I get isn't terribly useful.  This is what is produced . . .

```
divide by zero StackTrace= [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@7734137 Cause= null ex= java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero

private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler onBlooey = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                putPref("storedexception", "Exception: " + ex);
        }
};
```

This doesn't tell me much.  Is there anyway I can get a stacktrace?  Anything that would tell me where in the program the error is occurring?
Thanks,
Dean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/how-can-i-convert-a-stack-trace-to-a-string, though IMHO it would be far better for you to adopt an existing solution here, such as [ACRA](http://acra.ch/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops.  Posted to soon.  Figured out the answer...

```
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler onBlooey = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                // quickly store the exception info and mail it to me nextime on startup
            debugLog("found uncaught exception: " + ex, true);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            ex.printStackTrace(pw);
            String st = "";
            st = sw.toString(); // stack trace as a string
            putPref("storedexception", "Exception: " + ex + " stacktrace: " + st);
        }
};
```