# Why do exceptions not have a convenient method to return the stacktrace as a string?

Tags: java, exception, language-lawyer

The other day I needed (admittedly for the first time) to get a stack trace as a string. `e.printStackTrace()` of course doesn't return one.

I needed to use the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1149712/3262003) answer to get what I wanted.

Yes I realise you can get the stack trace elements then iterate over them yourself, and there are 3rd party libraries that can do it in one line, but why is there nothing in the standard library which does this for you and returns a string?

Comment: Four lines of code?  Write a helper method.

Comment: It sounds a little petty, but then again why write 4 lines of code when you can write 1 line with a clean method call? I assume that's the reason it was included in many commonly used 3rd party libs

Comment: It's annoying but that is the way it is.    If you want to know _why_ you have to ask the architects at Oracle.

Comment: Well, maybe Sun/Oracle did not have the time to implement all the methods everyone needs. Otherwise we would not need any 3rd party lib at all, or, "why do they not implement the `doWhatCarlosNeeds` or `doWhatDonaldNeeds` method so we only have to write one line of code?"

Comment: "It sounds a little petty", but if three lines of code are too much extra, you could write your own utility method. Personally I question the value of collapsing a stack trace into a `String`. Whether for human or automated consumption, a list-like structure is easier to parse.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - FCS, can we spare ourselves from these *"yadda yadda you have to ask underspecified and unreachable-person at multi-million dollar company"* comments. Bah. What you *do* is, you ask on S.O. and hope that one of the actual experts is reading it. And while they're not reading it, *other* experts may come up with some good wisdom. (Or the <strike>mob</strike> community might close your question, *shrug*.)

Comment: @MartinBa Ah, a meta-comment.  Allow me to introduce you to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ where they belong.   You can read the introduction here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen You may think they belong on the meta graveyard. I comment to reach a specific audience.

Comment: @MartinBa Well, you can say so in a much less... shall we call it "colloquial way" to be polite.   You might even provide an actual answer to what is being asked while we wait for _other_ experts to say they don't know why either or the question to be closed.

Comment: Do you expect the JRE to provide *everything* you might ever need as convenience method, even if you are probably the only one on the planet needing this?

Answer (score 1):

I always use `e.toString()` it's quite enough.
If you want something more specific you can process the stack trace `String result = ex.toString() + "\n"; StackTraceElement[] trace = ex.getStackTrace(); for (int i=0;i<trace.length;i++) { result += trace[i].toString() + "\n";} return result;`

Comment: Sorry, i really don't know why Java creators didn't implemented an easier way to convert stacktrace element to string. I just can suppose that they considered that it wasn't so necessary for exception handling.

Comment: They fit all that code on one line, just like the question asked. Why would you question whether they read the question?

Comment: @LewBloch because I didn't ask how to get the stack trace as a string. Besides I already stated I knew about getting the stack trace elements, but he provided a solution for that too.

Comment: But you did say, "The other day I needed ... to get a stack trace as a string" and "... do it in one line, but why is there nothing in the standard library which does this for you and returns a string?" So, yes, you did ask how to get the stack trace as a string in one line, and this answer shows you a way to do that. Clearly they _did_ read your question so the snarkiness wasn't necessary.