# FileUtils.copyDirectory fails with a remote file larger than 7megas

Tags: java, groovy, apache-commons-io

FileUtils.copyDirectory fails with a remote file larger than 7 megas

Imports:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
```

Code:

```
String source = fm_dirIn;
File srcDir = new File(source);

// The destination directory to copy to. This directory
// doesn't exists and will be created during the copy
// directory process.
String destination = fm_dirOut;
File destDir = new File(destination);

try {
    // Copy source directory into destination directory
    // including its child directories and files. When
    // the destination directory is not exists it will
    // be created. This copy process also preserve the
    // date information of the file.
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
    return true
} catch (IOException e) {
    'Erreur : ' + e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Result

> Erreur : null and the copied list files stops on this file at 7040kb (it's 31944 KB)

the printStackTrace :

> Current stack trace is:java.io.IOException: Erreur réseau inattendue
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.pwrite0(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.pwrite(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.writeInternal(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFromFileChannel(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFrom(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:1131)
>       at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1424)
>           at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1366)
>           at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1246)
>           at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1215)
>           at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils$copyDirectory.call(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
>           at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:27)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:518)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:556)
>           at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:527)
>           at com.prosc.beanshell.BeanShellModel.evaluateGroovy(BeanShellModel.java:163)
>           at com.prosc.beanshell.BeanShellPlugin.EvaluateGroovy(BeanShellPlugin.java:603)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at com.prosc.fmkit.StaticFunction.invoke(StaticFunction.java:231)
>           at com.prosc.fmkit.Plugin.invokeFunction(Plugin.java:339)
>           at com.prosc.fmkit.RegisterablePlugin.invokeFunction(RegisterablePlugin.java:146)
>           at com.prosc.fmkit.Plugin.invokeFunctionNoErrors(Plugin.java:320)
>           at com.prosc.fmkit.PluginBridge$3.run(PluginBridge.java:1132)
>           at com.prosc.fmkit.PluginBridge$5.run(PluginBridge.java:1234)
>           at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: This doesn't compile. Please add the actual code and full stack trace.

Comment: For your information, since Java 1.7 you can copy a directory using the JDK. See [Copying a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html)

Comment: HI. this is  the actual code and full stack trace.
I use it in a filemaker plugin that runs java or groovy

Comment: If this is Groovy please tag as groovy. You have to improve your catch block. `printStackTrace()` prints the stack trace to stderr and doesn't return anything. Try removing catch block completely.

Comment: without catch > message box :
java.io.IOException: Erreur réseau inattendue
and in english :
java.io.IOException: Unexpected network error

Comment: it is possible that the parameters of the vpn disrupt the script ?

Comment: Fix a way how you get an error. printStackTrace returns no value (check the doc) that's why you have `erreur null` message. If your program has console or maybe log, the printStackTrace should  print full error to it.  Or you could use the following technique to get full error in string and return it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/how-can-i-convert-a-stack-trace-to-a-string

Comment: the printStackTrace is too long
I put it as answer

Comment: yes I add the all printStackTrace in the question

Comment: `Unexpected network error` issue not about the code, but about network restrictions. And you have to look for resolution on network/system administration forums.

Comment: ok 
Thank you ;)