# The JVM crashes while printing the stacktrace

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface, invocation-api

I want to convert an exception stacktrace to a string in C.
I have this code:

(main.c)

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
  JavaVM *jvm;
  JNIEnv *env;
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
  JavaVMOption *options = calloc(3, sizeof(JavaVMOption));
  assert(options);
  options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/usr/lib/java:.";
  options[1].optionString = "--enable-preview";
  options[2].optionString = "-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages";
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_10;
  vm_args.nOptions = 3;
  vm_args.options = options;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
  jint status=JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
  assert(status==JNI_OK);
  free(options);
  jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "A");
  assert(cls==NULL);
  jthrowable throwable=(*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env);
  if (throwable) {
    (*env)->ExceptionClear(env);
    //Following is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1149721/13912132
    jclass stringWriter = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/io/StringWriter");
    assert(stringWriter);
    jclass printWriter = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/io/PrintWriter");
    assert(printWriter);
    jmethodID noArgsConstructor =
        (*env)->GetMethodID(env, stringWriter, "<init>", "()V");
    assert(noArgsConstructor);
    jmethodID printWriterConstructor =
        (*env)->GetMethodID(env, printWriter, "<init>", "(Ljava/io/Writer;)V");
    assert(printWriterConstructor);
    jobject sw = (*env)->NewObject(env, stringWriter, noArgsConstructor);
    assert(sw);
    jobject pw = (*env)->NewObject(env, printWriter, printWriterConstructor,
                                   printWriter);
    assert(pw);
    jmethodID printStackTrace =
        (*env)->GetMethodID(env, (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, throwable),
                            "printStackTrace", "(Ljava/io/PrintWriter;)V");
    assert(printStackTrace);
    jstring string =
        (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, throwable, printStackTrace, pw);
    printf("%s\n", (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, string, NULL));
  }
  (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
}
```

(A.java)

```
public class A extends B{}
```

(B.java)

```
public class B{}
```

To reproduce this crash:

1. Compile main.c (`gcc -I $JAVA_HOME/include -I $JAVA_HOME/include/linux main.c  -L $JAVA_HOME/lib/server -ljvm -g3 -Og`)
2. Compile A.java and B.java (`javac *.java`)
3. Remove B.class (So the loading of A fails)

Now I wanted to execute a.out:

```
$./a.out
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3a78062056, pid=280779, tid=280779
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (15.0.1+9) (build 15.0.1+9-Debian-3)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (15.0.1+9-Debian-3, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x534056]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: /home/<userName>/dir/core
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/<userName>/dir/hs_err_pid280779.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugs.debian.org/openjdk-15
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And the corresponding crash file looks like this:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3a78062056, pid=280779, tid=280779
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (15.0.1+9) (build 15.0.1+9-Debian-3)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (15.0.1+9-Debian-3, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x534056]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: /home/<userName>/dir/core
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugs.debian.org/openjdk-15
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: --enable-preview -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages 

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, 8 cores, 7G, Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
Time: Sat Jan  2 08:35:27 2021 CET elapsed time: 0.039155 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00005568f9ab4dc0):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=280779, stack(0x00007ffc508ef000,0x00007ffc509ef000)]

Stack: [0x00007ffc508ef000,0x00007ffc509ef000],  sp=0x00007ffc509ed070,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x534056]
V  [libjvm.so+0x53413d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x9d6656]
V  [libjvm.so+0x9d8103]
V  [libjvm.so+0x77ff88]
V  [libjvm.so+0x780567]
j  java.io.PrintWriter.write(Ljava/lang/String;II)V+19 java.base@15.0.1
j  java.io.PrintWriter.write(Ljava/lang/String;)V+7 java.base@15.0.1
j  java.io.PrintWriter.print(Ljava/lang/String;)V+5 java.base@15.0.1
j  java.io.PrintWriter.println(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+14 java.base@15.0.1
j  java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+5 java.base@15.0.1
j  java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Ljava/lang/Throwable$PrintStreamOrWriter;)V+28 java.base@15.0.1
j  java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Ljava/io/PrintWriter;)V+9 java.base@15.0.1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x784c49]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8193eb]
V  [libjvm.so+0x819eec]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.io.PrintWriter.write(Ljava/lang/String;II)V+19 java.base@15.0.1
j  java.io.PrintWriter.write(Ljava/lang/String;)V+7 java.base@15.0.1
j  java.io.PrintWriter.print(Ljava/lang/String;)V+5 java.base@15.0.1
j  java.io.PrintWriter.println(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+14 java.base@15.0.1
j  java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+5 java.base@15.0.1
j  java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Ljava/lang/Throwable$PrintStreamOrWriter;)V+28 java.base@15.0.1
j  java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Ljava/io/PrintWriter;)V+9 java.base@15.0.1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000039

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000011 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007ffc509ed0f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00005568f9ab4dc0
RCX=0x0000000020000001 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000800149798 is a pointer to class: 
java.io.Writer {0x0000000800149798}
RSP=0x00007ffc509ed070 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00005568f9ab4dc0
RBP=0x00007ffc509ed080 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00005568f9ab4dc0
RSI=0x00000000fffffffe points into unknown readable memory: 00 00
RDI=0x00000008000097a8 is a pointer to class: 
java.lang.constant.Constable {0x00000008000097a8}
R8 =0x00005568f9ab5450 points into unknown readable memory: 0x00000008000270b0 | b0 70 02 00 08 00 00 00
R9 =0x00007ffc509ed0f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00005568f9ab4dc0
R10=0x00000008003fd6f8 is pointing into metadata
R11=0x000000080041c940 is pointing into metadata
R12=0x0 is NULL
R13=0x00007ffc509ed0f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00005568f9ab4dc0
R14=0x000000000000000f is an unknown value
R15=0x00007ffc509ed170 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00005568f9ab4dc0


Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000011, RBX=0x00007ffc509ed0f0, RCX=0x0000000020000001, RDX=0x0000000800149798
RSP=0x00007ffc509ed070, RBP=0x00007ffc509ed080, RSI=0x00000000fffffffe, RDI=0x00000008000097a8
R8 =0x00005568f9ab5450, R9 =0x00007ffc509ed0f0, R10=0x00000008003fd6f8, R11=0x000000080041c940
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00007ffc509ed0f0, R14=0x000000000000000f, R15=0x00007ffc509ed170
RIP=0x00007f3a78062056, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x002b000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007ffc509ed070)
0x00007ffc509ed070:   00005568f9ab4dc0 00007ffc509ed0f0
0x00007ffc509ed080:   00007ffc509ed0c0 00007f3a7806213d
0x00007ffc509ed090:   00007ffc509ed150 00007f3a78503fca
0x00007ffc509ed0a0:   00007ffc509ed0e0 00007ffc509ed290 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f3a78062056)
0x00007f3a78061f56:   c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 e8 fb 56 5a 00 83
0x00007f3a78061f66:   f0 01 84 c0 74 e4 48 8d 05 a8 42 c5 00 80 38 00
0x00007f3a78061f76:   75 08 b8 01 00 00 00 eb d3 90 4c 8d 25 84 42 c5
0x00007f3a78061f86:   00 41 80 3c 24 00 74 c2 48 8d 05 c3 d3 cb 00 80
0x00007f3a78061f96:   38 00 74 b6 48 8b 3b 8b 47 20 85 c0 79 6a a9 00
0x00007f3a78061fa6:   00 00 40 74 a5 48 8d 05 d6 2c c5 00 8b 00 83 f8
0x00007f3a78061fb6:   01 0f 94 c0 eb 96 0f 1f 40 00 48 8d 05 f9 3e c5
0x00007f3a78061fc6:   00 80 38 00 74 2c be 01 00 00 00 e8 8a 56 5a 00
0x00007f3a78061fd6:   84 c0 74 92 48 8b 3b be 04 00 00 00 e8 79 56 5a
0x00007f3a78061fe6:   00 84 c0 0f 85 61 ff ff ff e9 78 ff ff ff 0f 1f
0x00007f3a78061ff6:   40 00 48 8d 05 ed 2c c5 00 8b 30 e8 5a 56 5a 00
0x00007f3a78062006:   83 f0 01 e9 5a ff ff ff e8 dd 9f 5a 00 84 c0 0f
0x00007f3a78062016:   84 35 ff ff ff 41 80 3c 24 00 0f 84 2a ff ff ff
0x00007f3a78062026:   eb 83 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 54
0x00007f3a78062036:   45 31 e4 53 48 89 fb 48 8b 3f f6 47 21 04 75 3d
0x00007f3a78062046:   48 8d 05 bc 41 c5 00 80 38 00 74 0c 48 8b 47 08
0x00007f3a78062056:   66 81 78 28 40 1f 77 25 0f b7 47 28 83 e8 06 66
0x00007f3a78062066:   83 f8 20 77 25 48 8d 15 a2 90 98 00 0f b7 c0 48
0x00007f3a78062076:   63 04 82 48 01 d0 ff e0 66 90 45 31 e4 44 89 e0
0x00007f3a78062086:   5b 41 5c 5d c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 83 fe fe 74 23 8d
0x00007f3a78062096:   46 ff 45 31 e4 83 f8 03 77 e3 e8 bb 55 5a 00 5b
0x00007f3a780620a6:   83 f0 01 41 89 c4 44 89 e0 41 5c 5d c3 0f 1f 44
0x00007f3a780620b6:   00 00 48 8d 05 01 3e c5 00 44 0f b6 20 45 84 e4
0x00007f3a780620c6:   74 28 be 01 00 00 00 e8 8e 55 5a 00 84 c0 74 ad
0x00007f3a780620d6:   48 8b 3b be 04 00 00 00 e8 7d 55 5a 00 83 f0 01
0x00007f3a780620e6:   41 89 c4 eb 98 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8d 05 f5 2b c5
0x00007f3a780620f6:   00 8b 30 e8 62 55 5a 00 83 f0 01 41 89 c4 e9 7a
0x00007f3a78062106:   ff ff ff 90 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8b 07 48 8b 40
0x00007f3a78062116:   40 48 85 c0 74 04 c3 0f 1f 00 55 48 89 e5 41 55
0x00007f3a78062126:   41 54 49 89 fc 53 48 89 f3 be fe ff ff ff 48 83
0x00007f3a78062136:   ec 18 e8 f3 fe ff ff 84 c0 74 4a 48 8d 05 d3 40
0x00007f3a78062146:   c5 00 80 38 00 74 53 4c 8d 2d b7 40 c5 00 41 80 
....
```

(Whole log: https://pastebin.com/ZGEQPw3y, as it is too long)

I'm on debian sid, java 15

```
openjdk 15.0.1 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-Debian-3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-Debian-3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

It even crashes if I don't add any commandline arguments.

Edit:
The backtrace (gdb) is:

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007fd526b0f537 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007fd526ebd3b3 in os::abort (dump_core=<optimized out>, siginfo=<optimized out>, context=<optimized out>) at ./src/hotspot/os/linux/os_linux.cpp:1542
#3  0x00007fd527ac388a in VMError::report_and_die (id=<optimized out>, message=message@entry=0x0, detail_fmt=<optimized out>, detail_args=detail_args@entry=0x7ffef14f0ba8, thread=thread@entry=0x55d76b440d50, 
    pc=pc@entry=0x7fd5271e3056 <CompilationPolicy::can_be_compiled(methodHandle const&, int)+38> "f\201x(@\037w%\017\267G(\203\350\006f\203\370 w%H\215\025\242\220\230", siginfo=0x7ffef14f0f30, context=0x7ffef14f0e00, 
    filename=<optimized out>, lineno=0, size=0) at ./src/hotspot/share/utilities/vmError.cpp:1635
#4  0x00007fd527ac40cb in VMError::report_and_die (thread=thread@entry=0x55d76b440d50, sig=sig@entry=11, 
    pc=pc@entry=0x7fd5271e3056 <CompilationPolicy::can_be_compiled(methodHandle const&, int)+38> "f\201x(@\037w%\017\267G(\203\350\006f\203\370 w%H\215\025\242\220\230", siginfo=siginfo@entry=0x7ffef14f0f30, 
    context=context@entry=0x7ffef14f0e00, detail_fmt=detail_fmt@entry=0x7fd527b848ae "%s") at ./src/hotspot/share/utilities/vmError.cpp:1315
#5  0x00007fd527ac40fe in VMError::report_and_die (thread=thread@entry=0x55d76b440d50, sig=sig@entry=11, 
    pc=pc@entry=0x7fd5271e3056 <CompilationPolicy::can_be_compiled(methodHandle const&, int)+38> "f\201x(@\037w%\017\267G(\203\350\006f\203\370 w%H\215\025\242\220\230", siginfo=siginfo@entry=0x7ffef14f0f30, 
    context=context@entry=0x7ffef14f0e00) at ./src/hotspot/share/utilities/vmError.cpp:1321
#6  0x00007fd527800fc2 in JVM_handle_linux_signal (sig=sig@entry=11, info=info@entry=0x7ffef14f0f30, ucVoid=ucVoid@entry=0x7ffef14f0e00, abort_if_unrecognized=abort_if_unrecognized@entry=1)
    at ./src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_x86/os_linux_x86.cpp:601
#7  0x00007fd5277f4738 in signalHandler (sig=11, info=0x7ffef14f0f30, uc=0x7ffef14f0e00) at ./src/hotspot/os/linux/os_linux.cpp:4738
#8  <signal handler called>
#9  0x00007fd5271e3056 in CompilationPolicy::can_be_compiled (m=..., comp_level=-2) at ./src/hotspot/share/compiler/compilationPolicy.cpp:118
#10 0x00007fd5271e313d in CompilationPolicy::must_be_compiled (comp_level=-2, m=...) at ./src/hotspot/share/compiler/compilationPolicy.cpp:79
#11 CompilationPolicy::compile_if_required (selected_method=..., __the_thread__=__the_thread__@entry=0x55d76b440d50) at ./src/hotspot/share/compiler/compilationPolicy.cpp:86
#12 0x00007fd527685656 in CallInfo::set_common (__the_thread__=<optimized out>, index=15, kind=CallInfo::vtable_call, selected_method=..., resolved_method=..., resolved_klass=0x800149798, this=0x7ffef14f16d0)
    at ./src/hotspot/share/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp:128
#13 CallInfo::set_virtual (__the_thread__=<optimized out>, vtable_index=15, selected_method=..., resolved_method=..., resolved_klass=0x800149798, this=0x7ffef14f16d0) at ./src/hotspot/share/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp:91
#14 LinkResolver::runtime_resolve_virtual_method (result=..., resolved_method=..., resolved_klass=<optimized out>, recv=..., recv@entry=..., recv_klass=recv_klass@entry=0x800007438, 
    check_null_and_abstract=check_null_and_abstract@entry=true, __the_thread__=<optimized out>) at ./src/hotspot/share/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp:1424
#15 0x00007fd527687103 in LinkResolver::resolve_virtual_call (__the_thread__=0x55d76b440d50, check_null_and_abstract=true, link_info=..., receiver_klass=0x800007438, recv=..., result=...)
    at ./src/hotspot/share/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp:1311
#16 LinkResolver::resolve_invokevirtual (__the_thread__=0x55d76b440d50, index=<optimized out>, pool=..., recv=..., result=...) at ./src/hotspot/share/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp:1689
#17 LinkResolver::resolve_invoke (result=..., recv=..., pool=..., index=<optimized out>, byte=byte@entry=Bytecodes::_invokevirtual, __the_thread__=__the_thread__@entry=0x55d76b440d50)
    at ./src/hotspot/share/interpreter/linkResolver.cpp:1633
#18 0x00007fd52742ef88 in InterpreterRuntime::resolve_invoke (thread=thread@entry=0x55d76b440d50, bytecode=Bytecodes::_invokevirtual) at ./src/hotspot/share/interpreter/interpreterRuntime.cpp:854
#19 0x00007fd52742f567 in InterpreterRuntime::resolve_from_cache (thread=0x55d76b440d50, bytecode=<optimized out>) at ./src/hotspot/share/interpreter/interpreterRuntime.cpp:991
#20 0x00007fd50efb1aac in ?? ()
#21 0x00007fd5087300f0 in ?? ()
#22 0x00007fd50efb1a72 in ?? ()
#23 0x0000000000000021 in ?? ()
#24 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Edit 2:

While trying to resolve this issue, I disassembled PrintWriter::write:

```
public void write(java.lang.String, int, int);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;II)V
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=4, locals=6, args_size=4
         0: aload_0
         1: getfield      #97                 // Field lock:Ljava/lang/Object;
         4: dup
         5: astore        4
         7: monitorenter
         8: aload_0
         9: invokevirtual #101                // Method ensureOpen:()V
        12: aload_0
        13: getfield      #43                 // Field out:Ljava/io/Writer;
        16: aload_1
        17: iload_2
        18: iload_3
        19: invokevirtual #136      <--This instruction is crashing          // Method java/io/Writer.write:(Ljava/lang/String;II)V`
        22: aload         4
        24: monitorexit
        25: goto          36
        28: astore        5
        30: aload         4
        32: monitorexit
        33: aload         5
        35: athrow
        36: goto          57
        39: astore        4
        41: invokestatic  #123                // Method java/lang/Thread.currentThread:()Ljava/lang/Thread;
        44: invokevirtual #129                // Method java/lang/Thread.interrupt:()V
        47: goto          57
        50: astore        4
        52: aload_0
        53: iconst_1
        54: putfield      #35                 // Field trouble:Z
        57: return
```

I was able to reproduce it on windows. (Java 15, too)

Edit 3:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  JavaVM *jvm;
  JNIEnv *env;
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
  JavaVMOption *options = calloc(3, sizeof(JavaVMOption));
  assert(options);
  options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/usr/lib/java:.";
  options[1].optionString = "-verbose";
  options[2].optionString = "-Xcheck:jni";
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_10;
  vm_args.nOptions = 3;
  vm_args.options = options;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
  jint status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
  assert(status == JNI_OK);
  free(options);
  jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "A");
  assert(cls == NULL);
  jthrowable throwable = (*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env);
  (*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env);
  if (throwable) {
    (*env)->ExceptionClear(env);
    jclass stringWriter = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/io/StringWriter");
    assert(stringWriter);
    jclass printWriter = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/io/PrintWriter");
    assert(printWriter);
    jmethodID noArgsConstructor =
        (*env)->GetMethodID(env, stringWriter, "<init>", "()V");
    assert(noArgsConstructor);
    jmethodID printWriterConstructor =
        (*env)->GetMethodID(env, printWriter, "<init>", "(Ljava/io/Writer;)V");
    assert(printWriterConstructor);
    jobject sw = (*env)->NewObject(env, stringWriter, noArgsConstructor);
    assert(sw);
    jobject pw = (*env)->NewObject(env, printWriter, printWriterConstructor,
                                   printWriter);
    assert(pw);
    jmethodID printStackTrace =
        (*env)->GetMethodID(env, (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, throwable),
                            "printStackTrace", "(Ljava/io/PrintWriter;)V");
    assert(printStackTrace);
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, throwable, printStackTrace, pw);
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, stringWriter, "toString",
                                        "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    printf("%s\n", (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(
                       env, (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, sw, mid), NULL));
  }
  (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
}
```

I fixed the issue with `CallObjectMethod`, but it still crashes.

Comment: You can't in general call ***any*** JNI fucntions with an exception pending.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#exception_handling for the few exceptions.

Comment: The exception is being cleared by the OP, so that shouldn't be a problem. Could try adding `-Xcheck:jni` as a VM option as well to see if that turns up anything.

Comment: There is no exception pending. `jthrowable throwable=(*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env);` here, it is pending. I enter the if-Statement, and then I make `(*env)->ExceptionClear(env);`.

Comment: @JornVernee I tried it, everything is okay. -Xcheck:jni gave no warnings/errors

Comment: I found one error: `jstring string =
        (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, throwable, printStackTrace, pw);` is wrong. This still doesn't lead to a crash. If I change it, to the right version, it still crashes

Comment: @JornVernee Do you think, it could be a bug in the JVM? Or did I somehow miss something?

Comment: @JCWasmx86 It might be. You could try with the [latest EA build](http://jdk.java.net/17/) to see if that has the same problem and then file a bug (see the "Feedback" section on the EA page).

Comment: @JornVernee It still crashes, so I'm going to assume it's a bug. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JornVernee Is it possible to report a bug, without giving the real name, as I really don't want to connect my github/stackoverflow account with my real name?

Comment: @JCWasmx86 As far as I know you can fill in any name you like. Doesn't have to be real (could e.g. just use JCWasmx86).

Comment: The error is in line `NewObject(env, printWriter, printWriterConstructor, printWriter);` Be careful with arguments.

Comment: Good catch, thank you. @apangin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code, there were two issues:

Issue one:

```
jstring string =
        (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, throwable, printStackTrace, pw);
```

printStackTrace is a void-method, returning nothing. If this call would have succeeded, a garbage would be in `string`.

Fixed code:

```
(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, throwable, printStackTrace, sw);
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, stringWriter, "toString",
                                        "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring string = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, sw, mid);
```

The second issue (Thanks for pointing it out @apangin) was, this line:

```
jobject pw = (*env)->NewObject(env, printWriter, printWriterConstructor,
                                   printWriter);
```

Normally, the signature of the printwriter constructor, I wanted to invoke would be:

```
PrintWriter(Writer w);
```

But I somehow messed it up with the arguments, and passed the class of the printwriter, so it would be essentially like executing:

```
PrintWriter(Class<PrintWriter>);
```

This worked until `java.io.PrintWriter.write(Ljava/lang/String;II)V+19`, as there is the first access to the bad object, leading to a crash.

The right line is now:

```
jobject pw = (*env)->NewObject(env, printWriter, printWriterConstructor,
                                   sw);
```